# Accessing instance variables in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I don't have any code as this is just a hypothetical question, but how would you go about accessing and manipulating instance variables in rspec?

For instance if you had a @counter variable in your initialize method inside of a class, how could you write a test saying that if @counter is a certain number, then a certain method should return true. And if it equals a different number, then that method should return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
describe Foo do
  context 'When counter is even' do
    let( :foo ){ Foo.new(4) }

    specify '#even?' do
      expect( foo.even? ).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

According to your question, `@counter` is set in the initialize method. So the `#even?` method would check `@counter`.

Comment: To clarify, the counter would not be set like that. A players name would be the argument in the initialize definition and the counter is automatically set to 0 when you initialize. After a player takes a turn, the counter increments by one each time

Comment: It sounds like you want a `#has_moved?` method. So that method would check the `@counter`. The above test will work.

Comment: Okay cool. I'll try and mess around with some code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Writing specs is a great way to learn. And then you can post your app and spec code in questions on SO to get better help.